# Capistrana will it be useful for executing remote rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, rake, capistrano, task

I want to execute some rake task from remote machine. 
Would Capistrano be useful for this case.

Here i am not going to do any deployment, so there will not be any code update. 
I wish to send some files to my rails project and execute the rake task.

Please suggest which could be suitable, only Capistrano comes in my mind. I am very new to Capistrano

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you can use is

1. $ cap shell
2. $ cap -vT

if you need remote console, log display, please take a look my [capistrano tasks on Github](https://gist.github.com/886438)